# How do I get created objects as a query set from django bulk_create?

Tags: python, django, orm, bulk-create

I am making use of bulk_create on a Django model. How can I get the values of the created object so I can proceed to make use of it, without querying the db again?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EduardoAlejandroLeyva, i use postgres

Answer (score 1):

The [**`.bulk_create(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) returns a list of the created items. Indeed:

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are), and **returns created objects as a list, in the same order as provided**.

So you can work, as the documentation states with:

> ```
> objs = Entry.objects.bulk_create([
>     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
>     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
> ])
> ```

where `objs` will be a list of two `Entry`s with the primary key filled in.

Answer (score -1):

When you send a post request after saving in database in the response you could see the data you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).